# Xamarin MasterDetailPage menu on UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I implemented MasterDetailPage into my app, but on Windows 10 the behavior seems a bit weird.
When the app starts, the menu is showing as expected. But when I click an item, it disappears with no way to go back or show the menu again.

It's simple to reproduce.. Download the sample: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage
Run the UWP app on Windows 10 and click any menu item. Now you're stuck on that page, with no way to navigate further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's weird.
To somewhat fix this issue, you can use the MasterDetailsPage MasterBehavior property, and change the behavior to one that doesn't seem odd.
You could also use some code to change it only when running on Windows, since the menu works correctly on Android and iOS.